# Sonar Eclipse plugin: Failed to download batch_bootstrap/db

Tags: sonarqube

I'm having issues with the Eclipse plugin of sonar. When executing it I'm getting the following exception in the Eclipse console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://<server>/batch_bootstrap/db?project=<project>]. Response code: 500
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:281)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:235)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:116)
    at com.google.common.io.Files.copy(Files.java:231)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.download(ServerClient.java:69)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.downloadDatabase(PreviewDatabase.java:101)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PreviewDatabase.start(PreviewDatabase.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 6 more
```

We're running SonarQube Server 4.1.2, the plugin version is 3.3.0.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Could this be related to poor DB performance (even though it's not some timeout exception)? Sonar runs on an Oracle DB, and we just updated sonar which resolved issues with excessively long query times (but weirdly enough only for logged in users). I added login information in the plugin settings though, so i assumed it should work.

When opening a source file in Eclipse, I'm getting messages like

```
Retrieve issues of resource ResultUtil.java...
Done in 43625ms
```

which sounds like the query would be running way longer that desirable.

**Update 2:**

We realized that even though the project existed in SonarQube, and was analyzed, it was not *provisioned* (the project was created with a pre 4.0 version of SonarQube). To rule out that caused the issue we provisioned a new project in SonarQube, ran the analysis on that and configured the eclipse plugin to use this new project.

This did not resolve the issue, either we're getting the same exception, or no further message at all. Calling the URL in a web-browser yields the same result (i.e. endlessly says "waiting for `<server`>".

The "SonarQube Web Browser" view of the eclipse plugin correctly shows issues, which I take as a sign that the plugin is configured correctly. Also, for some reason querying the issues from SonarQube is now a lot faster, so I would rule out that this caused the issue.
Any more suggestions on what we could check?

**Update 3**

We tried restarting SonarQube and then tried to analyze the project using the eclipse plugin. This failed with the above exception. Checking the SonarQube logs revealed these issues:

```
2014.03.19 11:17:35 ERROR [o.s.c.p.DbTemplate]  Fail to copy table rules
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: Unique index or primary key violation: "RULES_PLUGIN_KEY_AND_NAME ON PUBLIC.RULES(PLUGIN_RULE_KEY, PLUGIN_NAME)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO rules(ID,PLUGIN_RULE_KEY,PLUGIN_NAME,DESCRIPTION,PRIORITY,CARDINALITY,PARENT_ID,PLUGIN_CONFIG_KEY,NAME,STATUS,LANGUAGE,CREATED_AT,UPDATED_AT) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [23505-172]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1167) ~[h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbTemplate.copyTableColumns(DbTemplate.java:100) [sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbTemplate.copyTableColumns(DbTemplate.java:54) [sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DbTemplate.copyTable(DbTemplate.java:49) [sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.PreviewDatabaseFactory.copy(PreviewDatabaseFactory.java:87) [sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.PreviewDatabaseFactory.createNewDatabaseForDryRun(PreviewDatabaseFactory.java:63) [sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.preview.PreviewCache.generateNewDB(PreviewCache.java:121) [sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.preview.PreviewCache.getDatabaseForPreview(PreviewCache.java:81) [sonar-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.createDatabaseForPreview(JRubyFacade.java:471) [JRubyFacade.class:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
(... snip ...)
```

followed by

```
2014.03.19 11:17:35 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://hulk:9000/batch_bootstrap/db?project=E2PR-12.0
attempt to unlock read lock, not locked by current thread
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.unmatchedUnlockException(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:447)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryReleaseShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:431)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1340)
    java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.unlock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:883)
    org.sonar.core.preview.PreviewCache.getDatabaseForPreview(PreviewCache.java:92)
    org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.createDatabaseForPreview(JRubyFacade.java:471)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
(... snip ...)
```

Subsequent analysis runs triggered by the eclipse plugin seem to hang at `11:28:46.317 DEBUG - Download: http://hulk:9000/batch_bootstrap/db?project=E2PR-12.0 (no proxy)`

I can provide the logfile if that would help you to find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of digging I was able to resolve this issue. What pointed into the right direction was this discussion: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/33747

In the end this was caused by duplicate manual rules in the RULES table. I have no idea how they ended up there, but they were *not* visible from the UI, which made it kinda hard to spot.
After deleting these rules in the DB I'm now able to trigger the analysis from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project has not been analyzed in SonarQube prior to running preview analyses in Eclipse. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse.

Comment: There are results in SonarQube for that code. However, the Project which is set-up in Sonar consists of multiple Eclipse-projects. Could this be an issue?