# Why do I get "Fail to download" when analyzing Eclipse project with SonarQube plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, sonarqube

I'm using Sonar to check code quality and we're now trying to use the [Eclipse plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/eclipse/) to use Sonar server's rules on local code. We've configured some projects fairly easy with [plugin's tutorial](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) and, when trying to analyze code, we get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://mysterioushost.com:9000/batch_bootstrap/db?project=some:project]. Response code: 500
       at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:281)
```

I've had DB team to check what's in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473908/sonar-eclipse-plugin-failed-to-download-batch-bootstrap-db), but all data look OK.

Does anyone know why could this be happening? Are we missing any configuration or any license/technical/whatever restriction to use Sonar for the IDE?

Comment: You are receiving 500 HTTP response code.  You should try restarting the Sonar Qube , and analyze again.

Comment: Nope, nothing. Thanks, though.